# Resizeable custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I built a custom control in wpf c#. I put it in the Shell xaml of my project among with other things. I want the user to be able with mouse down and drag to change the width. Is there any control I can put my custom one in order for that to happen?

Comment: There isn't such. You will have to come up with your own drag-and-drop resize solution for controls.

Comment: You need a Thumb on your control and handle drag the events of the Thumb yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685566/wpf-using-resizegrip-to-resize-controls for an example

Comment: Hi,
After searching I found this example which solves my problem. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745672(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: @user3060639 either delete this question or post the answer you've found. Don't leave it open forever, please.

Comment: It doesnt let me post my answer. Can you please post it for me so that if someone else has this issue they will see what I posted?

Answer (score 1):

After searching I found this example which solves my problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745672(v=vs.110).aspx

It is a gridsplitter between to columns and it enables resizing thr columns.

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.