# WPF: How to resize bars using mouse or touch

Tags: wpf, touch

I have grid / canvas that has some bars which looks like your ordinary bar chart. I'd like that the user can (using touch and mouse) resize these bars by  dragging at selected points - see image below:

[image]

So the 5 points drawn here would be where the user can resize.
New to WPF, I'm not sure how to approach this, or even search for the right solutions. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please check this link if it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685566/wpf-using-resizegrip-to-resize-controls

Comment: Thanks, yes using Thumb is actually what I have in works now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform mouse hover it will resize your grid control refer below code

```
 <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="barresize.MainWindow"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="640" Height="480">
        <Window.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbTB">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="2">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbTB">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="2">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Window.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="tbTB">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="tbTB">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Window.Triggers>

        <Grid >

            <Grid x:Name="grid1" Background="#00000000">

                <Grid Name="tbTB" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="30" Background="Blue">

                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I think I can transfer this to my use-case where the user needs to resize the box/bar with the mouse (or touch).